# RavenDB Temp path already used by another database instance

Tags: .net, deployment, umbraco, ravendb

I'm currently trying to deploy our new site, which uses Umbraco and uCommerce (umbraco package). Now, uCommerce uses RavenDB to store product information, and we have to rebuild that before we deploy our new version of our site.

We have two sites in our IIS:
production.site.com
production2.site.com

Our deploy script is as follows:

1. Get current live site
2. Get current preproduction site
3. Copy files and change preproduction directory to new folder
4. Call service to build raven indexes from scratch
5. Swap bindings of the two sites, so the preproduction site will be our new production site

The reason why we do it this way, is to ensure that indexes are build, and the AppPool is running, so our customers do not experience any slow loading of our site.

The problem happens after we swap the bindings. I experience a "Temp path already used by another database instance" exception.

If we recycle the app pool, everything works great, however we would prefer not to recycle it, to ensure a fast working webshop.

Do you guys have any experience/suggestions on what do to?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, make sure that you `Overlapped Recycle` is set to false.

Comment: Doesn't always work unfortunately. I always suggest to run raven as a windows service and not IIS site. If not feasable, apparently running in Azure web apps can corrupt your database, so hosting in RavenHQ is the best alternative.